# React Native - use constant from a file in an object on another file

Tags: react-native, import, constants

I am using react-i18next to have a multi lang app but I am not able to use constants when trying to build my vocabulary.

I am trying to export constants from a separate file and add these constants as keys in the language object on the translation (i18n) file. However, for some reason it does not let me do this and I get a compilation error.

It does not even recognize the other consts within the object. When I take it outside of the object, it works.

Is there a limitation I am not aware of?

Please see the en object in the index.js file as well as other relevant files:

Consts.js

```
import React from 'react'

export const Constants = {
    USERNMAE : 'Username',
    PASSWORD : 'Password',
    LOGIN : 'Login',
}
```

index.js

```
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

import {Constants} from '../constants/Consts'

//Constants.USERNAME works perfectly fine here

const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: {
      Constants.USERNAME: "Username", //doesn't work and doesn't recognize USERNAME at all
      "Password":"Password",
      "Login":"Login"
    }
  },
  he: {
    translation: {
      "Username": "שם משתמש",
      "Password": "סיסמא",
      "Login": "התחבר"
    }
  }
};

i18n
  .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .init({
    resources,
    lng: "he",

    keySeparator: false, // we do not use keys in form messages.welcome

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false // react already safes from xss
    }
  });


  export default i18n;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with imports here, but you can't use object value as an object key in that way

Try out to use an object literal (surround by [] brackets)

```
const resources = {
  en: {
    translation: {
      [Constants.USERNAME]: 'Username', // <---- now it works :)
      Password: 'Password',
      Login: 'Login',
    },
  },
  he: {
    translation: {
      Username: 'שם משתמש',
      Password: 'סיסמא',
      Login: 'התחבר',
    },
  },
}
```